# how to set my graph bar to be on bottom not at the center

Tags: delphi

my problem is when the amount have value the bar already set at the bottom but when the value is zero automatically my bar is set at the center...how i want to set my bar go to the bottom when amount is zero???

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum value on the Left Axis is set to Automatic by default.  Uncheck Auto and set an explicit maximum value, and the chart will draw as expected.